# Is it possible to use selectinload and yield_per on pymysql driver?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, eager-loading, pymysql

I tried to use selectinload and yield_per against a model.  It looks something like this:

```
some_histories = session.query(SomeHistory).filter(
    SomeHistory.created_at >= a_day,
    SomeHistory.created_at < next_day
).options(
    sqlalchemy.orm.selectinload(SomeHistory.children)
).yield_per(10)

count = 0
for some_history in some_histories:
    process_history(some_history)
    count = count + 1

print(count)
```

Execution of above command seems to fail to yield all the records; the printed count at the end was `16`, whereas it was much more (> 2000) if I remove the `options` method call and just call the `yield_per`.

I printed out sqlalchemy's log to see if there is any suspicious log, and it printed like:

```
/path/to/venv/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py:756: UserWarning: Previous unbuffered result was left incomplete
```

I suspect this to be the cause of this symptom, but not so sure.

#### Question

- When using SQLAlchemy on pymysql driver, is it possible to use `selectinload` eager loading strategy and also use `yield_per`, and make it work properly?

  - If it is the driver problem, is there any alternative driver which can achieve this purpose?

#### Environment

- python: 3.7.4
- sqlalchemy: 1.3.6
- pymysql: 0.9.3

Comment: Potentially relevant (and timely): https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/4786